# How can I set output volume of one specific sound source only in an ALSA mixer?

Tags: alsa

I've got a sound solution, which plays sounds from different sources (MP3, CD, speech synthesizer) via ALSA. To allow more than one source (of which only one plays sounds at the same time), I configured `dmix` as the default ALSA sound device, which in turn talks to the `plughw` device, a JustBoom HAT sound card. This config works quite fine, but I haven't found a way to set the volume of the CD player sound source, which addresses ALSA directly (not via libraries) and hands the PCM data of the CD over to the sound device by using `snd_pcm_writei ()`. Because of the mixer, I also open the mixer by using `snd_mixer_open ()` and then address is by using a `snd_mixer_elem_t` object. I am **not** using PulseAudio or the Jack server.

My issue is now: How can I set the output volume of this particular sound source (the CD), leaving all other sound sources untouched? I've found out that `snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all ()` changes the volume of all sound sources (also MP3 and speech, not only the CD) working the mixer, but I'd like to, for instance, mute the CD and MP3, but set speech to full volume for announcements.

Comment: By default, there is no way to influence the volume before it arrives at the `dmix` plugin. You would have to create separate `softvol` devices on top of the `dmix` one.

Comment: …and each sound source would then attach to a separate `softvol` device, right? Do you have an example config you could post as an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no way to influence the volume before it arrives at the `dmix` plugin. Create separate `softvol` devices on top of the `dmix` one:

```
pcm.somedevice {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type softvol
        slave.pcm "plug:dmix"
        control {
            name "Some Playback Volume"
            card 0                        # must be same card number
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would then use `somedevice` for my CD output (with soft volume control) and the default device (here: a duplex device using `dmix` for playback), right?

Comment: Or multiple devices like this, if you need more volume controls.